# Unable to copy a file on chef-client (node)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have a file present in templates directory of my cookbook, and I am trying to copy that file to a node.

The **default.rb** of my cookbook is:

```
remote_file "#{ENV['HOME']}/p.txt" do
  source "file:///home/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks/remote_file/templates/default/p.txt.erb"
  mode "0644"
end
```

When I am doing a chef-client on the node I am getting following error:

```
[2014-04-03T18:44:25+05:30] INFO: Loading cookbooks [remote_file]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
[2014-04-03T18:44:25+05:30] INFO: Storing updated cookbooks/remote_file/recipes/default.rb in the cache.
  - remote_file
Compiling Cookbooks...
Converging 1 resources
Recipe: remote_file::default
  * remote_file[/home/node/p.txt] action create[2014-04-03T18:44:25+05:30] INFO:     Processing remote_file[/home/node/p.txt] action create (remote_file::default line 10)
[2014-04-03T18:44:25+05:30] WARN: remote_file[/home/node/p.txt] cannot be downloaded from file:///home/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks/remote_file/templates/default/p.txt.erb: No such file or directory - /home/chef/chef-repo/cookbooks/remote_file/templates/default/p.txt.erb

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 'remote_file[/home/node/p.txt]'
================================================================================


Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - /home/chef/chef-    repo/cookbooks/remote_file/templates/default/p.txt.erb
```

Why I am not able to copy the file on node. What am I doing wrong, Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't what you want to do, but it looks very weird. Why don't you just use the [template](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_template.html) resource?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to render a text file from a template (which it looks like you are), then use the `template` resource instead of `remote_file`:

```
template "#{ENV['HOME']}/p.txt" do
  source "p.txt.erb"
  mode "0644"
end
```

---

If instead it's just a simple static file that you're trying to get into the node, then the `cookbook_file` resource would be more appropriate. To use that, move your file to `<cookbook>/files/default/p.txt` and add the resource:

```
cookbook_file "#{ENV['HOME']}/p.txt" do
  source "p.txt"
  mode "0644"
end
```

Comment: I need to copy a file from the chef-workstation to a node, my workstation and node are on different machines, different IP,  and I beleive that for transferring files to remote remote_file commant is used in chef

Comment: If you know another way to copy file from my chef-workstation to a node, please let me know?

Comment: Ok... The reason why it's not working, is because Chef runs on the node, so when you point the `remote_file`'s source to `file:///something`, it tries to read the file from the local filesystem. In order to copy from a remote host you need to expose the file via either HTTP or FTP.
Either way it doesn't seem like that's what you want. If the file doesn't change often, you're better off using `cookbook_file` and adding the file to the cookbook. Otherwise, you probably need to set up a web or FTP server on an actual server and serving it from there.

Comment: Copying files from a workstation is usually a one-off thing and is better sone by SCP'ing the file manually. :)